# Having trouble using proxies with urllib

Tags: python-3.x, proxy, urllib

I am trying to utilize a proxy so that I can reach external data. My proxies do not appear to be working. I am using Python 3 and urllib.

I have tried feeding proxies = proxies to urlopen. I have tried using ProxyHandler.

```
#Importing dataframe and request stuff
import pandas as pd
import json
import urllib
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.request import ProxyHandler

#mapping proxy dictionary
proxies = {
    'ftp': 'ftp://x:80',
    'http': 'http://x:80',
    'https': 'https://x:80'
} 
#handling the proxy
proxy_support = urllib.request.ProxyHandler(proxies)
```

This below code may be irrelevant, but I do not know.

```
#Identifying the file
json_file = "https://gis.fema.gov/arcgis/rest/services/NSS/OpenShelters/MapServer/0/query?where=1%3D1&outFields=*&returnGeometry=false&outSR=4326&f=json"

#reading the file
data = urlopen(json_file).read()

#loading data
raw_json = json.loads(data)

#formatting data
formatted_json = [feature['attributes'] for feature in raw_json['features']]

#creating data frame
df = pd.DataFrame(formatted_json)
```

I keep timing out because my proxy isn't working, not sure exactly what I'm doing wrong.